# Сохранение результата после использования SKStoreReviewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Необходимо сохранить значение в userDefault именно только после оставления оценки приложению. А по факту получается, что даже если отказываешься поставить оценку, userDefault все равно записывает результат shareComplete. Подскажите, как реализовать? Спасибо

```
func rateApp() {
if #available( iOS 10.3,*){
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
openUrl("itunes.apple.com/app/id...")
}

fileprivate func openUrl(_ urlString:String) {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
        (success) in
           // срабатывает в независимости от того, поставил звездочку или нет
           shareComplete = true
           self.userDefault.set(shareComplete, forKey: "shareComplete")
           self.userDefault.synchronize()
        })
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официального способа узнать о результатах (и успешности) вызова `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` на данный момент не существует, существуют обходные способы ([например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008845/about-the-callback-of-skstorereviewcontroller-requestreview)) узнать о показе/скрытии диалога оценки, но использовать их, как водится, не рекомендуется. В вашем методе `openUrl` можно проверить лишь успешность открытия той или иной ссылки, не более того.

[Ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews?language=objc) на мануал Apple по работе с отзывами.